# Does Google calendar have an 'either or' search operator? Can my sheets script perform an 'either or' calendar search?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

My script pulls search term from specified sheets cells and searches my calendar. I'd like to conduct an 'either or' calendar search for multiple terms. I can't find a relevant search operator within Google calendar. Can my script be adjusted to accomplish? Can I add a 2d search variable for a 2d term and then adjust {search: to do an OR search?

```
     var search0 = sh1.getRange("A1").getValue();
     var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 
     2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(search0)});
```

`

Comment: No it doesn't, the query parameter is free text and searches for events with all the words supplied. You'll have to make two calls.